Would this lipo, driver, led circuit work?
Let's say

I had two 5000mah 100C 6S lipo batteries in parallel that are treated as positive and negative ends from a single power source, 22.2V across them
I wrapped the exposed ends of 28 different wires around either the positive or negative end of the lipo power source to make like a big ball of wound up wires drowned in solder forming a massive metallic ball, now having 28 wires branching from it. And the opposite terminal of the battery I keep as a single wire.
I put 28 300W/20A SZBK07 identical constant current drivers into parallel with this configuration and the drivers were calibrated to output 14.4A and 12V each (I think this is how it works and hopefully the current would be split through them equally).
On the output side of every driver, I connect 4 12V 3.6A LEDs in parallel.

There would be 26 more repeating loops (28 in total). Power source are the lipos, 22.2V

Now would this work or am I out of my mind? Are there any components I'm missing and would all the specs line up? Should all parallel circuits be used here for optimization (as opposed to series or mixture of series and parallel)?

Welcome! Please draw a schematic or block diagram of what you have and how you intend to connect it.

A schematic, even a hand-drawn diagram, would have saved you from typing many sentences.

So you propose to draw 560 amp from a 10 Ah battery - theoretically the battery will be fully discharged just over one minute.  In practice, you'll probably have melting wires, exploding batteries and other exciting events.

Could someone please look at the image I've added and tell me if the circuit is even slightly feasible? I acknowledge that the battery capacity would be short-lived but that's fine. I'm not very experienced in circuitry so if anyone could give any advice on this design or recommend any changes (eg: lacking components, knowledge of how something works), I'd really appreciate it.

No, will not work as described and is crazy amount of power delivery for a low voltage battery system. 100C discharge rate even for high-rate LiPo chemistry is crazy, and the total current levels would require very large wiring at the battery. The described single return wire to "the opposite terminal of the battery" will quickly melt.
Also, an LED with spec of "12V 3.6A" is typically a module that needs a 12V constant voltage source, rather than constant current driver for power.
The total proposed load power required is 4 LEDs/driver * 12V * 3.6A/LED * 28 drivers = 4840 Watts. The proposed power source is 10 AHr * 22.2V = 222 Watt-Hrs.  So as others pointed out, even with perfect power converters/drivers, total system run time is about 160 seconds.  My rough estimate, this proposal is equivalent to operating the lighting system for a sports field from a single car battery.
To power the proposed 28 groups of 12V 172W LED loads, a reasonable power source would be 28 separate 12V 20Ahr batteries and appropriate distribution fuses.

If I used 28 separate batteries, how could I still use a single switch for all of them?

To control a large electrical load switch from a small control signal, which might be a single manually operated switch, the typical solution is a coil-operated, normally open, electromechanical "relay" or "contactor" (name used for larger relays).   Placing small current through the coil pulls in (closes) a electrical contact that can pass a much larger current.

Many relays could be operated simultaneously, with the coils in parallel, from a single control switch or signal.

It might 'work', but in practice only for a short time.
(the constant current drivers would be in series with each load).
Each LED channel consumes 14.4 A @ 12 V; this leaves (22.2-12) = 10.2 V across each constant current driver. At 14.4 A, this makes the CC driver dissipate 14.4*10.2 = 147 W. With 28 of these, you'll dissipate over 4 kW.
Normally this type of system would use a DCDC converter which might 95 % efficient. This will a) reduce the power dissipated in the driver to a more manageable (but still manageable) 200 W, and b) consequently make the battery last nearly twice as long.

So are you saying that if I use lipos with a lower voltage, the energy dissipated in the drivers would be less? Actually, I believe I'd be using buck converters (difference between these and constant current drivers?) instead though I guess the logic would be similar right? Surely there'd be another way around this. Why would constant current devices be designed to waste energy when higher voltages are applied?

A constant current device is generally understood to be a circuit which only allows a fixed, predefined current, no matter what voltage is applied. If you mean a buck converter, that's a completely different structure, but is what I suggested (==DCDC converter). This can be configured to deliver a fixed current, but if you are using '12V' LEDs, they just need to receive 12 V.
